# How to fix footer position in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, footer

I have added a footer split into 3 columns in the `ui.R` in shiny application in the below format:

```
navbarpage(title="",
    footer=p(hr(),
          column(4, p()),
          column(4, p()),
          column(4, p())
 )
)
```

The footer keeps moving up and down between pages. Could it be possible to fix the footer position across the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```r
library(shiny)
navbarPage(
  title = "",
  tags$style(".footer{position:absolute;bottom:0; width:100%;}"),
  footer = tags$div(
    class = "footer",
    p(
      hr(),
      column(4, p()),
      column(4, p()),
      column(4, p())
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: It should be `position: fixed;` to pin the footer to the bottom page for a scrollable page.